# Alternate way to use linq to determine if an element does not exist in a collection?

Tags: .net, linq

I use:

```
if (!ObjectCollection.Any(o => o.Property == SomeValue))
    // ...
```

or:

```
if (!IntCollection.Contains(42))
    // ...
```

to determine if a collection does *not* have a particular element, but some people miss the `!` negation and misinterpret.

Is there another way to determine that a collection does not contain a particular element that doesn't use the negation operator? I prefer to stick to dot notation instead of query expression, but maybe a query expression is more readable to someone who misses the bang.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing in standard LINQ, but if you *really* don't like using `!` (which is the approach I'd recommend) you could always write your own extension methods:

```
public static bool DoesNotContain<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T item)
{
    return !source.Contains(item);
}


public static bool None<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    return !source.Any(predicate);
}
```

(You can use these for things like LINQ to SQL as well *if* you're just using them as the final call - you wouldn't be able to use them in nested queries though, as the query translator wouldn't understand them.)

Answer (score 1):

I understand your concern about readability for the ! operator.  Two common solutions I've used:

A) Put spaces around the ! so that it stands out and is easier to see a la

```
if ( ! IntCollection.Contains(42) )
    // ... the ! stands out
```

B) Write a readability extension method that makes it nicer

```
public static class Readability
{
    public static bool Missing<T>(this Enumerable<T> source, T value)
    {
        return ! source.Contains(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is replace `!` with `== false`

```
if (ObjectCollection.Any(o => o.Property == SomeValue) == false)
    // ...
```

And

```
if (IntCollection.Contains(42) == false)
    // ...
```